# Vue transition-group not taking effect

Tags: vue.js

I want to wrap a `v-for`-block inside a `transition-group`:

```html
<transition-group tag="div" name="fade" appear>
  <template v-for="(element, index) in listItemsUniqueIds" :key="element.uuid">
    <ItemList :index="index" :uuid="element.uuid" ...></ItemList>
  <template>
<transition-group>
```

The `fade` animation works just fine on a normal `transition`-tag. But the `transition-group` is not taking effect at all. The `keys` inside the `v-for` definitely are unique.

I also tried to replace the `template` tag with `div`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may have a fundamental misunderstanding of what the `transition-group` does. A `transition-group` applies an animation to the elements within the group, not on the group itself, this means that for the initial state of the transition group, there will be no animation until elements are added or removed. Another thing to note, an issue I have run into in the past is that your child elements may need to be enclosed in a `div` tag.

**From the docs**

> CSS transition classes will be applied to individual elements in the list, not to the group/container itself.
>
> (https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition-group.html#differences-from-transition)

---

Now with that being said, let's discuss how we can make a transition group work for your needs.

If you want the style to load onto each element you can do a recursive load with a timeout

```js
//Load the elements one at a time
loadArrayItems(items){
  setTimeout(()=>{
    this.listItemsUniqueIds.splice(0, 0, items[0]);//Add the first element to the global array
    if(items.length <= 0) return //No more items kill recurison     
    items.shift(); //Remove the zeroth element
    this.loadArrayItems(items); //Load the next element after 500ms
  }, 500);
}
```

[CodeSandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursive-load-z44hx2?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:477-501)

Or if you want the group to animate in you can just apply a transition tag above around the `transition-group`

```html
<Transition name="fade">
  <div v-if="items.length">
    <button @click="load">Load</button>
    <TransitionGroup name="fade" tag="ul" class="container">
      <div v-for="item in items" class="item" :key="item">
        {{ item }}
      </div>
    </TransitionGroup>
  </div>
</Transition>
```

[CodeSandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/transition-wrapper-fcb8po?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

Comment: I already understood, what transition-group was doing, but thanks for your detailed answer. The only problem I had was using the `transition-group` tag. I changed it to `TransitionGroup` and it worked. If you could explain this behavior I'd be grateful tho.

Comment: I am not sure, it is odd cause the version 2 of the documentation does list it as `transition-group` and version 3 lists it as `TransitionGroup` however, when looking at it, it appears that even in version 2 that only `TransitionGroup` works.